# How to handle nested objects in Laravel Eloquent's models?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have an object, created like this : `$object = new Object($datas)`

Here, $datas is an array **(coming from an API, not a database)** :

```php
$datas = [
    'prop1' => 'value1',
    'prop2' => 'value2',
    'prop3' => 'value3',
    'nestedObject' => [
        'propa' => 'valuea',
        'propb' => 'valueb',
        'propc' => 'valuec',
    ],
];
```

If I do nothing, $object->nestedObject is an array.
However, I want it to be an object implementing the NestedObject class.

---

In order to do that, I defined a cast for the nestedObject property :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Object extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'nestedObject' => \App\Casts\NestedObjectCast::class,
    ];
}
```

And the NestedObjectCast :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Casts;

use App\Models\NestedObject as NestedObjectModel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;
use InvalidArgumentException;

class NestedObjectCast implements CastsAttributes
{
    /**
     * Cast the given value.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return \App\Models\NestedObject
     */
    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        if($value !== null) {
            return new NestedObjectModel($value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the given value for storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  \App\Models\NestedObject $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return array
     */
    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return [$key => $value];
    }
}
```

It works !
Now, $object->nestedObject is an instance of the class NestedObject.

But something bothers me : In the NestedObjectCast class, in the set() method, **$value should be an instance of NestedObject class** (That what the documentation say), **but it's not the case**. When I write a var_dump() inside this method, $value is an array or null.

**So, obviously, even if it works, there is something wrong with my code, but what ???**
Also, I was a bit surprised that I have to write a NestedObjectCast class to do  such simple action. **Is there another/better way to do this ?**

Comment: This is not how Laravel is supposed to be used. What you call a nested object is in fact a Relationship. So my question is: why are you not using relationships?

Comment: @Luciano I may be wrong (I'm new to Laravel) but it seems that I can't use Relationship in this case (i.e. without database). If I try to define a one to one relationship, Laravel display an error : "table nested_objects doesn't exists". I don't want Laravel to search for datas in the database, the datas for the nested object already are in $object->nestedObject (array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want get an array of NestedObject by command `$object = new Obj($datas);`, just build a construct function in Object class like my Obj class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\NestedObject as NestedObjectModel;

class Obj extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'nestedObject' => \App\Casts\NestedObjectCast::class,
    ];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {
        if (!empty($attributes['nestedObject'])) {
            $attributes['nestedObject'] = new NestedObjectModel($attributes['nestedObject']);
        }
        parent::__construct($attributes);

    }
}
```

Note: Can not create class with name Object, because it’s a reserved word in PHP.

Comment: Thank you. One little comment : Unless I'm mistaken, the cast `\App\Casts\NestedObject::class` is not needed anymore.